# How can I access Enum member attributes without .value (and without using a tuple of positional args)?

Tags: python

When using Enums, I much prefer not having to use `.value` everywhere to access member attributes.

So, I create them like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum

@dataclass
class Item:
    foo: int
    bar: int

class Collection(Item, Enum):
    A = 1, 2

# Now I can use Collection.A.foo
```

However, my `Item` class has several arguments, and for readability (and IDE support), I would prefer instantiating Items directly on the Enum.  Something like this (which doesn't work, since Enum wants a tuple of positional arguments, not an instance of `Item`):

```py
class Collection(Item, Enum):
    A = Item(1, 2)
```

While still enjoying `Collection.A.foo` attribute access (instead of `Collection.A.value.foo`, which is what I'd get if I had `Collection(Enum)`).

Or at the very least, be able to specify the keywords to be used to instantiate `Item`:

```py
class Collection(Item, Enum):
    A = dict(1, 2)
```

Is there a way to achieve either solution?  Maybe with some hacking of `Item.__new__`?

Edit: I'm trying not to use tuples on the Enum.  (At the time of writing this, both answers still used tuples to define the arguments to Items.)

Comment: Have you considered just not to use an enum, but a regular collection (list, set, dict, ...) or module?

Comment: The IDE checking of Enum types is useful.  But yes, we've fought enums enough that vanilla classes as containers (i.e., not subclassing Enum) are looking pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

[From Python's `Enum` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#when-to-use-new-vs-init) - You can try overriding the `__init__` or `__new__` of your enum class and achieve your desired output.

Take note of the following part from the documentation on when to override which one:

> #### When to use __new__() vs. __init__()
>
> **new**() must be used whenever you want to customize the actual value of the Enum member. Any other modifications may go in either __new__() or __init__(), with __init__() being preferred.
>
> For example, if you want to pass several items to the constructor, but only want one of them to be the value (Refer to the `__new__` overriding)

Look at those two examples:

Overriding `__new__`:

```
>>> class Coordinate(bytes, Enum):
...     """
...     Coordinate with binary codes that can be indexed by the int code.
...     """
...     def __new__(cls, value, label, unit):
...         obj = bytes.__new__(cls, [value])
...         obj._value_ = value
...         obj.label = label
...         obj.unit = unit
...         return obj
...     PX = (0, 'P.X', 'km')
...     PY = (1, 'P.Y', 'km')
...     VX = (2, 'V.X', 'km/s')
...     VY = (3, 'V.Y', 'km/s')
...

>>> print(Coordinate['PY'])
Coordinate.PY

>>> print(Coordinate(3))
Coordinate.VY
```

overriding `__init__`:

```
>>> class Planet(Enum):
...     MERCURY = (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6)
...     VENUS   = (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6)
...     EARTH   = (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6)
...     MARS    = (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6)
...     JUPITER = (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7)
...     SATURN  = (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7)
...     URANUS  = (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7)
...     NEPTUNE = (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7)
...     def __init__(self, mass, radius):
...         self.mass = mass       # in kilograms
...         self.radius = radius   # in meters
...     @property
...     def surface_gravity(self):
...         # universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
...         G = 6.67300E-11
...         return G * self.mass / (self.radius * self.radius)
...
>>> Planet.EARTH.value
(5.976e+24, 6378140.0)
>>> Planet.EARTH.surface_gravity
9.802652743337129
```

By using one of those methods, you can create your own, more customisable, Enum classes. Even if you also need your `Item` class as a separate class from the enum, you can just override one of those two functions and make it work (Though if `Item` was created only for the sake of the Enum, you should probably merge it inside).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the traditional way of setting in the `__init__` method which requires no additional classes. Detailed explanation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet).

```
from enum import Enum
    
class Collection(Enum):
    A = 1, 2
    B = 3, 4
    C = 5, 6
    D = 7, 8

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
```

**Trial Run**

```
for item in Collection:
    print(item.foo, item.bar, sep=', ')
```

**Result**

> ```
> 1, 2
> 3, 4
> 5, 6
> 7, 8
> ```